# How to show cache images when app goes in Offline in Picasso in Android

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I am using Picasso image loader its working fine when application run on network but i when kill application from recent and make network/ wifi OFF and start application then all cached images not showing... is it possible to show all cached images when goes in offline and restart application by killing.

If any another library or another way available for it please tell me or suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
.load(imageUrl)
.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)  //this line will help
.into(imageView, new Callback() {

@Override
public void onSuccess() {

}

@Override
public void onError() {
    //Try again online if cache failed
    Picasso.with(getActivity())
            .load(posts.get(position).getImageUrl())
            .error(R.drawable.header)
            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            Log.v("Picasso","Could not fetch image");
        }
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Picasso only uses a memory cache which gets destroyed together with your application. You should use an okhttp disk cache for offline caching.